# How can i display the merged contents of local files from a js+html page running locally

Tags: javascript, html, file-access

I have a bunch of files(not necessarily text files) on disk. I need to display the merged contents of all these files in a html page opened locally on Load. Is this possible without using Active-X? My objective is to create a summary of a set of files and at the same time to keep the summary file small. Infact most of the files whose data I need to summarize are html files.

If this is possible can I also choose only certain sections of text in each file to be part of the summary?

It would be great if the solution would have a wide browser support.
Any example would help a lot.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Open the files in iframes then pull the source of each and process it.  Since it is coming from your own machine, there should not be any cross-domain problem.

Comment: how do i get the source of an iframe?

Comment: Any help please.. I dont want them to exist as separtae entities in the final summary as iFrame does.... I need to merge their contents... How can I pull the source from an iFrame??

Answer (score 0):

Javascript does not have access to the clients file system, therefore I do not believe this is possible.  See this post: [Local file access with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript)

Comment: well it is possible actually using Active-X only for IE though. All of my files or an a local system and I would be collecting them into a html page in the same system.